# Poco XML does not compile with XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T - How to compile Poco C++ v1.12.4 to support Unicode

Tags: unicode, build, poco, poco-libraries

Getting compilation errors in Poco XML module (XMLStreamParser.cpp , SAXParser.cpp ) while building with preprocessor definition "XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T".

With "XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T" defined, Poco::XML::XMLString is treated as std::wstring. Getting compilation errors for conversion from Poco::XML::XMLString to std::string.

Tried to compile Poco C++ v 1.12.4 on Visual studio 2019 developers command prompt using <poco_base_dir>/buildwin.cmd.
Before executing buildwin.cmd setting preprocessor definition "XML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T" by running below command:
set CL=/DXML_UNICODE_WCHAR_T